# Метод link_to неправильно генерирует роут для ссылки на удаление

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Есть ссылка с методом `:delete`:

```
= link_to "Удалить", posts_path(@post), method: :delete
```

Однако в разметке выходит путь `/posts.6`, а не `/posts/6`. **Почему?**

Comment: Если не сложно выполните команду rake routes, как выглядит её отчет?

Comment: Вставьте код в виде текста, а не изображения.

Comment: ...всё равно там нужна только последняя строчка, уже из неё всё ясно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Замените `posts_path` на `post_path`.

Comment: Спасибо, просто в роутах у меня было написано в множественном числе
`DELETE /posts/:id(.:format) posts#destroy`